# how to require 'confirm by email' to create an account in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have a site built on mediawiki. How do I ensure that to create a new account the user must first confirm his email by clicking a link sent to his email address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that that I know of although you can get pretty close.  The  [$wgEmailConfirmToEdit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgEmailConfirmToEdit) variable let's you prevent people from editing unless they have confirmed their email address.  Just set:

```
$wgEmailConfirmToEdit = true;
```

in your LocalSettings.php

Comment: Or you can do `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false; $wgGroupPermissions['emailconfirmed']['edit'] = true;`, which works for any other permissions as well.

Comment: Right but that doesn't help with confirming email before creating an account either. Also $wgEmailConfirmToEdit has a couple important side effects. For example, if its set to true it makes the email field on the create account form required.

Comment: Technically you need to create an account so there is an email address to confirm; except some CMSes disable the account until the confirmation so the user cannot log in. You could probably do the same in MediaWiki (IIRC globally banned users cannot log in so the functionality is there), but it's more work than worth. Fair point about the required field.

Comment: Agreed. An custom extension combining locked accounts and the email confirmation functionality would probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Instead as another protection can one add a field to the form when someone creates an account? Then make a 'honey pot' -> We make that field hidden, and if it gets filled in by a bot, we don't let the form be processed? I'm trying to prevent spam accounts being created. I do have fancy captcha but it doesn't work 100%>